# regex phone number and url with numbers collision

Tags: c#, regex

I have a little c# program that get plain text and needs to turn phone numbers into phone number links (it's run on a mobile device) and regular urls into clickable links.

I have written the following regex for phone:

```
(((\d)(-)?)+){7,15}
```

and the following for urls:

```
((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)?[&#95;.a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])
```

the phone regex is run before the url regex does. and in most cases they seem to be running and acting fine.

but I have a problem with the following text:

```
line 1
line 2
052-1234567
line 3
http://www.facebook.com/SomePage/app_1234567890
```

what happens is that it sets the phone number (052-1234567) correctly, and it sets the url up to the number (http://www.facebook.com/SomePage/app_) correctly. The number in the end of the url is also recognized as a phone number.

I have 2 problems:

1. if I comment out the phone number I see that the url regex ignores the numbers at the end.
2. since the phone number regex replace happens before the url regex replace it catches the number in the url as a phone number.

what I was thinking is somehow changing the phone number regex so if it only starts with numbers then it will be valid (or simply saying catch a pattern that does not start with...).

And of course - why is my url regex not working with the numbers at the end?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I was able to solve the url regex problem by adding another * just before the last closing bracket.

```
((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)?[&#95;.a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)]*)"
```

Comment: Shouldn't adding a `^` before your phone number regex solve it?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi tired that - when I add one it doesn't recognize any. unless I'm using it wrong. can you write an example?

Comment: FYI every time you write `[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)]` fifty kittens drown... :) It's hard to tell exactly but I think you meant this: `[^ .'#!?,;<>()]` Basically a charclass already means this char OR that char so the `|` do not belong. Likewise, there is no need to escape chars such as `#` etc.

Comment: As @zx81 you have to work out with your regex since you did not mention what is the expected format of data.

Comment: A phone number as you define it is also valid as part of a URL. A good general rule is to order your tests so that the biggest or most-restrictive one is tested first.